# Parallels dynamic stages in separate containers

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have this pipeline that generates dynamic stages based on file content. I want the stages to run on different containers, so I thought to move the agent{docker{image ''}}} label to inside the stage in the generateStage() function but it's not possible since it's a scripted pipeline. How can I run these stages on separate containers, and still run them parallelly and generate them dynamically?
Would really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

```
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: job") {
            //do something
        }
    }
} 

pipeline{
  agent none
  stages{
    .
    .
    .
    stage('parallel stages') {
      agent { 
        docker{
          image 'some-image:tag'
        }
      }
      steps {
          script {
            def list = ["STAGE-A", "STAGE-B"....] // DYNAMIC LIST CREATED FROM A FILE
            parallelStages = list.collectEntries{
              ["$it": generateStage(it)]        
            }
            parallel parallelStages
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the agent option, you can do something like the below.

```
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: job") {
           docker.image('your-image').inside {
              sh 'DO SOMETHING'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your comment!
This method is still running the stages on the same docker container.
However, I solved the problem by adding something extra!
What worked for me was to wrap the returned stage with node ("some node"){} label.
Thanks again!